# How to switch between transform-origin and scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code above who switch between CSS transform-origin and scale to CSS width and scrollbars.

I need to make this switch because I am having a pinch to zoom for a DIV wrap I'm using in my website.

I'm using CSS translateX and translateY and Scale for a smoother pinch zoom, but after the zoom take place, I need to return back to width and scrollbar so the user can move across the layout.

I have here an example of how I'm doing the switch and there is a bit margin on top that I can't really set mind my on.

what is the correct way to do so?

```js
var isOrigin = false;
        var originX = 500;
        var originY = 200;
        var scale = 1.5;
        var deltaX = 0;
        var deltaY = 0;

        var from_origin_to_scroll = function () {
            if (isOrigin) { from_scroll_to_origin(); return; }

            var wrap = $('.containter .wrap');

            //reset scroll
            const el = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;
            $('.containter')[0].scrollLeft = 0;
            el.scrollTop = 0;

            wrap.css({
                transformOrigin: originX + "px " + originY + "px",
                transform: "translate3d(" + deltaX + "px," + deltaY + "px, 0) " +
                              "scale3d(" + scale + "," + scale + ", 1) ",
                width: 100 + '%'
            });

            isOrigin = true;

            $('.info').html('layout set by origin and scale');
        }

        var from_scroll_to_origin = function () {
            var wrap = $('.containter .wrap');

            wrap.css({
                transformOrigin: originX + "px " + originY + "px",
                transform: "translate3d(" + 0 + "px," + 0 + "px, 0) " +
                              "scale3d(" + 1 + "," + 1 + ", 1) ",
                width: (100 * scale) + '%'
            });

            $('.containter')[0].scrollLeft = originX * (scale - 1);

            const el = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;
            el.scrollTop = originY * (scale - 1);

            isOrigin = false;

            $('.info').html('layout set by width and scroll');
        }
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-x: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            width:100vw;
        }

        .top{
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
            line-height: 40pt;
            text-align: center;
            color: #f1f1f1;
            font-size: 20pt;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 10;
        }

        .top .info{

        }
        
        .header_content
        {
          background-color: #e1e1e1;
          line-height:130pt;
        }

        .containter {
            width:100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            overflow: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }

        .containter .wrap {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .containter .wrap img {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 30pt;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
        <div class="info" onclick="from_origin_to_scroll()">click to switch</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header_content">
    this is a header content - needs to be added to overall calculation
    </div>
    <div class="containter">
        <div class="wrap">
            <img src="https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/91858/594887747/stock-photo-dreams-of-travel-child-flying-on-a-suitcase-against-the-backdrop-of-sunset-594887747.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1020994/556702975/stock-photo-portrait-of-a-happy-and-proud-pregnant-woman-looking-at-her-belly-in-a-park-at-sunrise-with-a-warm-556702975.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/234100/599187701/stock-photo-funny-little-girl-plays-super-hero-over-blue-sky-background-superhero-concept-599187701.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1316512/661476343/stock-photo-funny-pineapple-in-sunglasses-near-swimming-pool-661476343.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2114402/689953639/stock-photo-adult-son-hugging-his-old-father-against-cloudy-sky-with-sunshine-689953639.jpg" />
            <img src="https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/172762/705978841/stock-photo-businessman-looking-to-the-future-for-new-business-opportunity-705978841.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please specify your question. I read it four times and I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: thank you @MiXT4PE, please run the code snippet and click the header with the title "click to switch". this will toggle between two states. one is set with css Transform and the other with scrollBars movements and width resize. I want to make them equal and I cant do this

Comment: Even by running the code snippet, both your expectations and your problem are unclear

Answer (score 3):

In your case the possible solution is to detect when the user is trying to zoom, and when just to scroll.

```
const $container = $(".container");
$container.on('touchstart', function (e) {
  if (e.touches.length > 1){
    //more than one finger is detected on the screen,
    //change mode to transform-origin
    from_scroll_to_origin()
  }
});

$container.on('touchend', function (e) {
  //change mode to scrollbars
  from_origin_to_scroll()
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for comment. But I still can't see how this works